# bean.getValue() only pulling in part of the value not entire value

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, javabeans

I am currently using a javaBean to save/load values to and from a jsp. Here what is happening:

I have the following line in my jsp:

```
<td><input class="partDescription" name="partDescription" style="width: 250px" type="text" readonly="readonly" value=<%=affectedBean.getPartDescription().get(i) %> /></td>
```

When I debug through the code this is value stored in the affectedBean.getPartDescription at index 0: BK SLOPE CONTROLLER

However, when it the page finishes loading the only thing it shows is in that location is: BK

Other examples:

Value: ROLF REDESIGNED UL SUPPLY; Displays: ROLF
Value: 18 FUEL SENSOR; Displays: 18

Anybody have any ideas

Comment: Why are you using scriptlets instead of EL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML elements, spaces are a special separator character for HTML element attributes like `type`, `value`, etc.

When printing attribute values without doublequotes like follows

```
<input type="text" value=<%=affectedBean.getPartDescription().get(i) %> />
```

then the generated HTML ends up as

```
<input type="text" value=BK SLOPE CONTROLLER />
```

All parts beyond the space are been interpreted as another attributes. A bit intelligent syntax highlighter should already have turned on some light above your head. It's colored differently!

So, you need to put quotes around the value

```
<input type="text" value="<%=affectedBean.getPartDescription().get(i) %>" />
```

so that the generated HTML ends up as

```
<input type="text" value="BK SLOPE CONTROLLER" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using *scriptlets* is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files), you should prefer using taglibs/EL. Assuming that you've put the `affectedBean` as attribute of the request, do so:

```
<c:forEach items="${affectedBean.partDescription}" var="partDescription">
    <input type="text" value="${partDescription}" />
</c:forEach>
```